# Zend framework session data to form fields

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm working on a multistep form and also there are previous buttons in that. When a user clicks the previous button they go a step back as expected, but the form is not filled with the data that is already filled in that step.

The data is stored in a session, so i thaught this wil work (in the controller):

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('previous')){
       $data = $this->sessionContainer->PlaatsenAdvertentie; 
    }
    else{
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
    }

    $form->setData($data);

     $viewModel = new ViewModel([
    'form' => $form
]);

return $viewModel;

}
```

But no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function inside the form class:

```
public function populate($step,$data)
    {
        foreach($data['step'.$step] as $field => $value){
            //uitgezond de submit en vorigestap buttons
            if ($field != 'submit' && $field != 'vorigestap'){
                $this->get($field)->setValue($value);
            }
        } 
        return $this;   
    }
```